# Passing an Outlook 2011 message to an AppleScript

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I am an AppleScript newbie, and am trying to automate part of my workflow, based on Outlook's ability to run an AppleScript when filter conditions on incoming email are met.

I've worked out the rest of the AppleScript, but am stuck on one part. How do I pass the message that just came in which meets the filter conditions (and may be part of a group of incoming messages) to AppleScript so that I can operate on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at the message via `current messages`

e.g,

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set msgs to current messages

    repeat with m in msgs
        set subj to the subject of m
        say subj
        display dialog subj giving up after 3
    end repeat

end tell
```